# QStyledItemDelegate + QTreeView::setIndenation causes glitches on text drawing

Tags: qt, qt5

It has been two days I can not get the solution.

I have a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` and a `QTreeView`. `QTreeView's` indentation set to 12. And `QStyledItemDelegate's` `QStyleOptionViewItem::rect` set to -12.
This set up causes glitches when I change the color of the `QTreeView` item's text.

[image]

**CODE**

```
void MyItemViewDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem* option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (m_functor->operator ()(index))
    {
        option->rect.adjust(-12, 0, 0, 0);
    }    
}

MyTreeView::MyTreeView(QWidget* parent)
    : QTreeView(parent)
{
    setIndentation(12);
}
```

What did I miss?

Somehow it relates with QTreeView's viewport.

Comment: remove option->rect.adjust(-12, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you for your effort. I have got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What I forgot to do was to override:

```
    QRect QTreeView::visualRect(const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
        if (m_functor->operator ()(index))
        {
            return QTreeView::visualRect(index).adjusted(-m_indentation, 0, 0, 0);
        }

       return QTreeView::visualRect(index);
    }
```